# When joining vertices, am I forced to use MEMORY_ONLY caching?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

Looking at the source of `outerJoinVertices`

I wonder if this is a bug or a feature

```
override def outerJoinVertices[U: ClassTag, VD2: ClassTag]
      (other: RDD[(VertexId, U)])
      (updateF: (VertexId, VD, Option[U]) => VD2)
      (implicit eq: VD =:= VD2 = null): Graph[VD2, ED] = {
    // The implicit parameter eq will be populated by the compiler if VD and VD2 are equal, and left
    // null if not
    if (eq != null) {
      vertices.cache() // <===== what if I wanted it serialized? 
      // updateF preserves type, so we can use incremental replication
      val newVerts = vertices.leftJoin(other)(updateF).cache()
      val changedVerts = vertices.asInstanceOf[VertexRDD[VD2]].diff(newVerts)
      val newReplicatedVertexView = replicatedVertexView.asInstanceOf[ReplicatedVertexView[VD2, ED]]
        .updateVertices(changedVerts)
      new GraphImpl(newVerts, newReplicatedVertexView)
    } else {
      // updateF does not preserve type, so we must re-replicate all vertices
      val newVerts = vertices.leftJoin(other)(updateF)
      GraphImpl(newVerts, replicatedVertexView.edges)
    }
  }
```

**Questions**

1. If my graph / joined vertices are already cached via another `StorageLevel` (e.g. `MEMORY_ONLY_SER`) - is this what causes the `org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.ShippableVertexPartitionOps ... WARN ShippableVertexPartitionOps: Joining two VertexPartitions with different indexes is slow.`?
2. If this is the case, then is this a bug in Spark (this is from 1.3.1)? couldn't find the JIRA issue on this if it is (but I didn't look too hard...)
3. Why is it not as trivial to fix as to provide this method a new StorageLevel?
4. What are the workarounds for this? (one that I can think of, is to do create a new Graph with vertices.join(otherVertices) and originalGraph.edges or something... but it feels wrong...

Comment: I agree that this seems to be a problem.  I would suggest that the code use the StorageLevel that the graph has been initialized with for its vertices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think it's actually not a bug.

Looking at the code for `VertexRDD` it overrides the cache method, and uses the original `StorageLevel` used to create this vertex.

```
  override def cache(): this.type = {
    partitionsRDD.persist(targetStorageLevel)
    this
  }
```